# Why this snippet isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my small snippet?

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
   if ($(window).width() < 770) {
      $(".side-by-side.right div").each(function() {
          $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
      });
   } else {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent().find('img'));
   }
});
```

The first command just above the else works, but what after the else dose not, what am I doing wrong? I am positive it is something tiny like the place of } or ) or maybe forgot to add ; somewhere!

http://jsfiddle.net/fD265/

Comment: if it was a missing bracket or whatever, you'd be able to see that by looking at your browser's debug console. e.g. ctrl-shift-J in firefox.

Comment: oh! thank you will give it a try now.

Comment: Please show off you HTML or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not clear, what you are trying to achieve, this may be, what you are looking for?

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 770) {
        $(".side-by-side.right div").each(function() {
            $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
        });
    } else {
        $(".side-by-side.right div").each(function() {
            $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent().find('img'));
        });
    }
});
```

In the else block, `this` references window instead of the object, you want to edit.

Comment: This answer fixed my problem, thank you - however, any ideas of how I would be able to add the width of scrollbar to the window width?

Comment: You could try `window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth`. Alternatively, when using jQuery, `$('body').innerWidth();` should also work.

Comment: I replace if ($(window).width() < 770) { with if ($window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth) < 770) { ?

Comment: `window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth` gives you the width of the scrollbar, which you can include in your calculation.

Comment: I did some research but still have no clue to implemented please can you help me out?

Comment: What about `$(window).width() + (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48006/discussion-between-softcreatr-and-loai)

Answer (score 1):

In the else statement, you're trying to reference the parent of the window object.  That's why it's not doing anything--there is no parent of the window object.

The first part (if) works, because in that .each() $(this) will refer to your div elements.  The $(this) in the else is still referring to window.

Fixing it will depend on what you're trying to do--which I can't really tell.  But, that's at least why it's not working.  :-)